# Running cucumber table automatically

Tags: automation, cucumber

I have a cucumber scenario with a data table in this way:

Scenario: Login functionality

Given loginscreen

When I enter Email as `<Email>` and Password as `<Password>`

```
| Email   | Password     |

| xxxxxx  | mypassword   |

| abcde   | mypassword   |

|         | mypassword   |

|         |              |
```

Then Login should be unsucessful

How can I run the step for all the table rows on an automated way. The only one solution I have found is going over every single cell in this way:

```
data.get(1).get(0)  , data.get(1).get(1) , data.get(2).get(0)  ,  data.get(2).get(1) ans so on.
```

Is it possible that cucumber runs the test for all the table values by itself?

Comment: Use a 'Scenario Outline' instead... That will run each of user-password combination as separate test.

Answer (score 0):

As @Grasshopper said, use the `Scenario Outline` instead:

```
Scenario Outline: Login functionality
  Given loginscreen
  When I enter Email as <Email> and Password as <Password>
  Then Login should be unsucessful
  Examples:
  | Email   | Password     |
  | xxxxxx  | mypassword   |
  | abcde   | mypassword   |
```